# Connection between two custom App Engines

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I connect between two App Engines?

I want to run a custom runtime with nginx for serving my frontend files and an other App Engine serving the backend with nodejs.

In my "one server setup" i use nginx to proxy everything from /api/ to localhost:3000 (my node instance)

I think i could start the Backend, look up the internal ip and proyx to that but i'd guess thats not the right way and it wouldn't allow me to test locally with gcloud app run.

Comment: are you talking about for local development only?

Comment: No, thats the point ;) I want to have a solution that fits both local and deployed.

Comment: look into modules then to split up functionality. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/ You know, of course, you won't be able to use nginx or anything like it when deployed right?

Comment: Why can't I use nginx when deployed? Maybe in my case it's simpler to use the static_dir stuff to serve my frontend but there is even an example project for using nginx on App Engine (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-nginx-hello)

Comment: that's not appengine. That's the managed VM service.